# Error in react-native app. Warning: The <Unknown /> component appears to be a function component that returns a class instance

Tags: react-native

I have a react-native application, and it writes the following error on startup:

```
 ERROR    Warning: The <Unknown /> component appears to be a function component that returns a class instance. Change Unknown to a class that extends React.Component instead. If you can't use a class try assigning the prototype on the function as a workaround. `Unknown.prototype = React.Component.prototype`.
```

But the application itself starts and doesn't crash. Does anyone have any idea what this error could be and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

More error:

```
 Don't use an arrow function since it cannot be called with `new` by React.
    in Unknown (created by Connect(Component))
    in Connect(Component) (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.tsx:899)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at StackViewCard.tsx:93)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at screens.native.js:71)
    in Screen (at StackViewCard.tsx:80)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.tsx:95)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.tsx:971)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at screens.native.js:101)
    in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.tsx:383)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at StackViewLayout.tsx:379)
    in PanGestureHandler (at StackViewLayout.tsx:372)
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.tsx:103)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Transitioner.tsx:267)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.tsx:40)
    in StackView (at createNavigator.js:61)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createAppContainer.js:429)
    in NavigationContainer (at create-redux-container.js:72)
    in NavigatorReduxWrapper (at NavigationRouter.js:115)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at react-native-drawer/index.js:579)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at react-native-drawer/index.js:566)
    in Drawer (at NavigationRouter.js:98)
    in NavigationRouter (created by Connect(NavigationRouter))
    in Connect(NavigationRouter) (at RootContainer.js:203)
    in RCTSafeAreaView (at SafeAreaView.js:51)
    in ForwardRef(SafeAreaView) (at RootContainer.js:199)
    in RootContainer (created by Connect(RootContainer))
    in Connect(RootContainer) (at Erta.js:33)
    in Provider (at Erta.js:32)
    in Erta (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

Comment: Hello, give this to your question, here it will be lost. You can edit your question.